# SVG image background repeat x

Tags: css, svg, cross-browser, background-image, background-repeat

I'm using an SVG image (pattern) as a background to get this effect: 
I use `background-repeat: repeat-x;` to make it responsive.

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYoAF.png)

In some browsers, there's a little gap between the repeated SVG images.

Is there a way to do this in CSS *(keeping cross-browser compatibility in mind)*?

Comment: This question is useless without your SVG markup. Please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem and include it in your question.

Comment: I just want a vector based pattern in CSS. The pattern I'm looking for is the example image in my post.

Comment: That's not a pattern, it's a raster image.